# keeping a function always running in django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django project where I'm suppose to check a date with today's date and if it's difference is of 1 month then there should happen something. Is there any method or any thing that can help me pls do help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [Django's management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) by writing your own, and then you can call it periodically via a cronjob.